# netsuite Arabic language localization

Tags: localization, internationalization, netsuite, arabic, suitecloud

netsuite by default doesn't support Arabic language i.e the forms,records and fields in netsuite appear in english.I thought that if i can change the translation of a form or record by customizing it i can change the field label translation and map it to a language under the localization preferences such as English international.

my problem is that not all records,forms and portlets can be customized I have tried under customization > centers and tabs > center categories  to add for each field the necessary translation for arabic language but this is applicable to certain fields only and not all fields such as payment > setup > bank details or customization > lists,records & fields > entity fields.
also i can't change the text of the configuration pages such as the ones that are under customization. I also tried to add translation to this fields from mass update but the same problem occurs not every thing can be translated. Also when switching the language from home > set preferences > localization > language

i can't find the Arabic language so i mapped my translation to other language such as English international then switched to that language

my main question is that how to edit the language preferences under home > set preferences > localization > language to add a new language?
And it there any better way to change netsuite to arabic?

and how to make my changes seen  to other roles so that any user of netsuite can view these changes?